# TypeScript mapped type change value function's return type

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript type like this:

```js
type Api = {
  createItem: (name: string) => Promise<Item>;
  getItem: (id: number) => Promise<Item>;
  updateItem: (item: Item) => Promise<Item>;
  deleteItem: (id: number) => Promise<void>;
};
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to convert it to the following:

```js
type Api = {
  createItem: (name: string) => { type: 'success'; result: Item; } | { type: 'error' };
  getItem: (id: number) => { type: 'success'; result: Item; } | { type: 'error' };
  updateItem: (item: Item) => { type: 'success'; result: Item; } | { type: 'error' };
  deleteItem: (id: number) => { type: 'success' } | { type: 'error' };
};
```

I think mapping types are a way to go here:

```js
type NewApi = {
  [_ in keyof Api]: (???) => { type: 'success'; result: ??? } | { type: 'error' }
};
```

I'm unable to figure out how to fill in the blanks there though. I'm not even sure it is possible to do that.

The reason I need this type is that I am building a gateway proxy and the actual implementation of the type will be an actual `Proxy` object intercepting the member accesses, mocking their values with another proxy which traps function invocation for a change and returns the above union type.

The implementation part is fine, but I can't seem to be able to get the type for it to get Intellisense working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of typescripts [Parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1471-L1474) and [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) types

```
type NewApi = {
  [K in keyof Api]: (...args: Parameters<Api[K]>) => { type: 'success'; result: ReturnType<Api[K]> } | { type: 'error' }
};
```

Please see this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=12&ssc=3&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oEMB2IDcAoXokUAgmAJYpQDeuUUAxgE4RrxyIBcUAFBmghC4BnYIzIYA5gEoUAPigAFRgHsEZIRAA87BLLx0JEYDq7cyAEy4YArggBGERjOTylq9Vp17aUa2HOsECY8ZPAIXDrOripqGtph3nTmEAA2RkFhphZWtg5OcooxHpoAbsoW3gC+eATg0AByEADupBSoNHQA2gDSUOJQANYQIMoAZiTkALqmAHRzaIwSQlwKC-zpjEKarT2TslHUUISCUADkQtb09BBCQqfYUMwXKcBcAEpG1owYACp12+RdvJKlAAD6HY5cU6OFSMU5QSq4aq4IA).